# Como esconder dado em uma tabela conforme o status

Tags: jquery, mysql, cakephp-2

Eu tenho um código que busca os dados no banco e imprime na tela uma tabela. A minha tabela que aparece na tela do usuário tem os campos:

```
  Referência    | Abertura  |Status     |Objeto
```

Referencia é um ID, Abertura é uma data e hora, Status é uma `string` e Objeto é um texto.

Essa tabela acima, busca do banco de dados os "editais" cadastrados pelo administrador, em uma outra tela. Nessa tela do cadastro de editais, eu fiz uma outra tabela no banco de dados que registra o status que tava e o status que passou a ser e para mostrar e imprimir na tela quando o usuário(adm) faz uma alteração de Status.

Na tabela que imprime(acima) os dados que usuário precisa saber, eu preciso que o Status suma dessa tabela após 30 dias quando ele for alterado para Sem Sucesso ou Revogado.

Como eram duas tabelas no banco, diferentes, quando fiz o `select` eu tive que fazer um sub-select para trazer os dados de status_alterado e a data da ultima alteração.

Depois disso eu fiz um `if` para testar se o status_alterado tem data menor do que 30 dias apartir do dia de hoje porém nao deu certo dessa maneira:

```
  // $dados um mysql_fetch_array com o dados do select que eu fiz //


   if ( ( $dados['status_alterado'] === "Sem Sucesso") && ( $dados['data'] <= date("m-d-Y") - 30) ) {

       echo 'olar';
  }
  else {
      echo 'oi';
  }
```

eu fiz exatamente esse `if`, porém ele sempre cai no `else`, eu já alterei no banco um dado que eu inseri como teste hoje 25/03/2015 para 25/01/2015, mas mesmo assim o `if` pula para o `else`.

Comment: Posta o esquema da tabela e alguns resultados, pra a gente ter como enxergar os dados e entender como corrigir a função de data

Comment: Esse `if` tem problemas de sintaxe nos parentesis. Acho que deve ser `if (($dados['status_alterado'] === "Sem Sucesso") && ($dados['data'] <= date("m-d-Y") - 30)) {`. Para além disso `date("m-d-Y") - 30)` está confuso, o que queres fazer com essa comparação? tirar 30 dias à data? ou 1 mês? de qq maneira não é esse o caminho. Explica um pouco melhor para podermos ajudar mais.

Comment: o meu if correto é esse:
[link]
if  (  ($editais['status'] == "Sem Sucesso")   &&   ($editais['data'] + 30 <= date("Y-m-d"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer a comparação de datas, você precisa fazer algo assim:

```
if (strtotime($dados['data']) <= strtotime('-30 days')) {
    echo 'mais de 30 dias';
} else {
    echo 'menos de 30 dias';
}
```

Aqui um exemplo no **[Ideone](https://ideone.com/UYYfP9)**. Além disso, como foi dito, você precisa verificar a sintaxe em relação aos parênteses.

Comment: Isso mesmo, Obrigado Paulo